# 3D Manipulator hotkeys or addon?

Tags: add-on, 3d-manipulator

There was an addon where when you press crtl space it would bring up a menu for the manipulator. I found an addon for it called Manipulator Menu which you could hit crtl space and you could select from a pop up widget to use rotate location scale manipulator instead of having to click down on the bottom and I believe even if you just keep hiting crtl space it will cycle throw the 3 different transform rotate and scale. I had a virus alil while about had to delete everything of my PC and now I can not find this anywhere in the addons or even a working link.

I couldnt find the addon anywhere so my question is does anyone know a working link to that or if there is another way to do this so with like hotkeys or maybe like a script or something. I tried googling it and than addons forums at blender artists and even looked at http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/ and not single one o them had a mod I could download.

I know it came from an older verison on blender under addons but now I cant find it for the love of me lol. If anyone can point me in the right direction for the addon or help me figure out how to change the keybinds to keys that arent used in blender. I have a logitech 8 button mouse but I just need to know what keys are not being used and wont mess up any of shotcuts. Hell if you have a work link that would be even better but I would appericate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the default pie-menu add-on that comes with blender?

Comment: I think maybe 3D View: Manipulator Menu add on? It's included with 2.78RC2 in testing category.

Comment: Yeah Timarqberts that one but its not showing up in my blender 2.78 am I going to have to download the RC2 again to just add this addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the addon. It was in the 2.78 RC2 files like you said Timaroberts thank you. I was hoping I wasnt going to have to use the whole 3d pie menu thing because I dont really like it. The menu I got from the RC2 2.78 is a pie version- of it but oh well its only that one pie menu and not all the other ones. Heres the link if anyone wants it:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Manipulator_Menu
If anyone needs the file lmk I know I can stand going back and fourth with the manipulator lol so now I just have to hit crtl space and it works kind of like how the other one did expect this one has the pie radial thing and not just the menu but thats not a problem because thats the only pie menu =P.

Again thanks for the help. Hope someone looking for that addon from 2.77 can find this so it will help someone else to. Well thanks again =)